# Select varchar max in Codeigniter returns unknown characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter, varchar

In sql management studio, it returns the text. But in `codeigniter` it returns something like:

```
n?g%'!?>?eHH!!X??HI!??
??W.
```

But if I changed it to `varchar(8000)` it returns the text.

Why?

Here's my query:

SELECT TOP(50) A.*,
                    RIGHT('000'+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.MajorArticleCode), ''),3) AS MajorArticleCode, B.MajorArticleDesc, 
                    RIGHT('000'+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.MinorArticleCode), ''),2) AS MinorArticleCode, C.MinorArticleDesc
                FROM LIB_Items A
                LEFT JOIN LIB_Major_Articles B  ON A.ACCode = B.ACCode AND A.MajorArticleCode = B.MajorArticleCode
                LEFT JOIN LIB_Minor_Articles C ON A.ACCode = C.ACCode AND A.MajorArticleCode = C.MajorArticleCode AND A.MinorArticleCode = C.MinorArticleCode

And here's my LIB_Items table structure

[LIB_Items table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAcTG.png)

Comment: Can you provide the entire query you are trying to run + your table layout?

Comment: Hi @JeroenvanVeghel, I have updated my post. Thanks